# Auto Select Key down for key of keyboard

Tags: c#

i need help for this cod
i want key down for PC after the if in the code like this

if(e.key press==shift)
Key down="w"

Example: I press SHIFT + E after that PC  press Key down or select it and active my keyboard key like (W)or .... Key

Answer (score 0):

When Shift-E is pressed, we send "W"?

Use [SendKeys.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netcore-3.1)?

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode==Keys.E)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("W");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is very LACKING.  Give more details about the type app.  Where do you want these keys to go?  The same app?  A different app?  "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful in getting us to help you.

Comment: I want this things  when  i press shift or any key  the program automatical press another key      example    i press shift and after that program will press another key like (W)  from keyboard

Comment: Do a search for RegisterHotKey().